# Why can we drop the superscripts in the Floyd Warshall algorithm?

Tags: dynamic-programming, shortest-path

In the lecture notes, our professor mentioned that we can take down the space taken by the FW algorithm from $O(n^3)$ to $O(n^2)$ by dropping all the superscripts in the matrices (i.e. use one $n\times n$ array $D$).

I just want to check my understanding, is it because by default $D^k=D^{k-1}$ except for the values $i,j$ where $d_{ik}^{k-1}+d_{kj}^{k-1}<d_{ij}^{k-1}$ where we set $d_{ij}^k=d_{ik}^{k-1}+d_{kj}^{k-1}$ but in essence we are using the values in the $D^{k-1}$ matrix to update itself?

However, what if we change one value, say $d_{i_1j_1}^k$ in the $kth$ iteration but then we need to reuse the value $d_{i_1j_1}^{k-1}$ later on in the same $kth$ iteration, wouldn't it be lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically in iteration k no entry $d_{ij}$ can change if $i=k$ or $j=k$. Since you update the entries in $D$ by considering $d_{ik}$ and $d_{kj}$ you can do all these updates in-place.

However there is an even simpler argument if you only want to show that the algorithm requires $O(n^2)$ space. At every iteration $k$ the values in $D^k$ only depend on the previous matrix $D^{k-1}$. Therefore it is enough to store the matrix $D^{k-1}$ of the previous iteration, use it to fill the next matrix $D^k$ and then you can safely discard $D^{k-1}$. So you only ever need to keep two matrices in memory and arrive at $O(n^2)$ space. Of course no sensible implementation would actually do this but it is enough to show the space bounds.

Comment: May I also ask you that even the $\prod^k[i,j]$ matrix can also be done this way such that the superscript $k$ can be removed and requires only one such $n\times n$ matrix to print out the shortest path?

Comment: For the same but more detailed explanation see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156163/1267910

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the numbers $d_{ik}$ and $d_{kj}$ do not change when computing matrix $D^k$; distances either starting or ending in $k$ cannot be improved by looking for a path that travels via $k$ (or equivalently, $d_{kk}=0$).

The right-hand side of the instructions of the algorithm only involve these numbers on the $k$-th row and column. The algorithm will not change them. The other numbers are recomputed but not used, so can be overwritten in $D^{k-1}$ to get $D^k$.